# How do I restrict the allowed age when inputting date of birth

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
<input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="trip-start" value="2021-10-02">
```

How do I make it where the only allowed ages are between 15 and 80 at the time of filling the form.

Comment: Basic will be allowing `min.` `max.` values ,i.e, 15 year back from today date will be `min` and 80 years will be `max`

Comment: How do I make it dynamically change though. As in, if one day progresses in real time, how would I reflect that on the code so that it ensures they are 15 to 80 at the time of input.

Comment: Check out my solution, it will dynamically change the 'min' and 'max' values according to the current date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need Javascript to achieve what you want:

HTML:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="./<your-external-js-file>"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="trip-start" value="2021-10-02" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Add this to your external JS file:

```
window.onload = function() {
      var date = new Date();
      var dd = date.getDate();
      var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
      var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

      //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
      if (dd < 10) {
        dd = "0" + dd;
      }

      //Add a zero if one Digit (eg: 05,09)
      if (mm < 10) {
        mm = "0" + mm;
      }

      minYear = yyyy - 80; //Calculate Minimun Age (<80)
      maxYear = yyyy - 18; //Calculate Maximum Age (>18)

      var min = minYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;
      var max = maxYear + "-" + mm + "-" + dd;

      document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("min", min);
      document.getElementById("start").setAttribute("max", max);
    };
```

By doing this, whenever your document will get loaded, this function will be executed, which will calculate the minimum *(age<80)* and maximum dates *(age>18)* from the current date, according to the formula applied and set the **'min'** and **'max'** attributes to our input field.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you. I only have one problem and it's that this only works when implementing it as inline JavaScript but not when my HTML file is linked to an external JavaScript file, in fact it stops my other JavaScript code from working. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: You will need to call your script at the bottom of your page - after the DOM elements. If you check your browser's console, you will likely see an error stating that element with id start is undefined/doesn't exist.

Comment: @ringaroundtheflow Check out the changes, It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#start").change(function(){
  var userboddate = $(this).val();
  var useryear=  userboddate.split('-')[0] ;
  var currentyear ='2021';
 var diff=currentyear-useryear; 
  if(diff>=15 && diff<=80){
    alert(`correct age ${diff}`);
    
  }
  else{
    alert(`wrong age ${diff}`);
    $("#start").val('');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="age">
<label for="start">Date of birth:</label>
<input type="date" id="start" required="required" name="trip-start" value="2021-10-02">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<!- i hope this code help you ->
```